# Way to parse Python pandas DataFrame to Matrix Market (MM) Format?

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, pandas

Is there a built-in way to write a Python [pandas.DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) object (stored as 2x2 numpy.ndarray internally) to [Matrix Market (MM) format](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/reports/MMformat.ps)? I have use cases for both sparse and dense matrices.

When I say "built-in" here I mean built into the pandas package. If not pandas, then is there something that can take a DataFrame or an 2x2 numpy.ndarray and do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing built in to `pandas`, but if you have the full stack installed you can use `scipy`:

```
>>> import scipy.io, scipy.sparse
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2], "B": [3,0]})
>>> scipy.io.mmwrite("mmout", df)
>>> !cat mmout.mtx
%%MatrixMarket matrix array integer general
%
2 2
1
2
3
0
```

It'll also work for a sparse case:

```
>>> scipy.io.mmwrite("mmout", scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df))
>>> !cat mmout.mtx
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate integer general
%
2 2 3
1 1 1
1 2 3
2 1 2
```

although you'd have to construct a copy.

Comment: In order to properly write a sparse matrix, you need to first remove the `NaN` values. This can be done using `df.fillna(0)`. Then after you convert your `DataFrame` to a sparse matrix: `sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.fillna(0))` you can remove all 0 values using `sparse_matrix.eliminate_zeros()`, which is an in-place operation.